# ActiveDirectory "No such object on the server"

Tags: c#, active-directory

This is my code:

```
userObject = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<SID=" + sid + ">");
if(userobject == null) {
    dbg.Add("Found no user for SID " + sid);
} else {
    dbg.Add("Found a user with SID " + sid);
    if (userObject.Properties[propName] == null || userObject.Properties[propName].Count == 0)
    {
        dbg.Add("userObject has no property " + propName);
    } else {
        dbg.Add("userObject has a property " + propName);
        ...
    }
```

The last dbg string I get is:

```
Found a user with SID S-1-5-21-2227...
```

and the error thrown is

```
There is no such object on the server
```

How could that be? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object won't be null even if it doesn't find something, so, the tracing isn't really accurate. A good way to see if you actually have an object is to try accessing the `userObject.NativeObject` property.